# How to handle IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption in android

Tags: android, exception

I am working on encryption decryption using AES and is working fine.But for the security checks i have done some changes in a file. Now again when i am running it is crashing on the line where it throws error of

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
```

. 
I have put log's and flags but it is not reaching the next line.Please suggest me how to handle this exception. I used try catch also but not working. The code snippet is":

```
            DataBaseActivity myDbHelper;
        File myFile1 = new File(filing1);   //Date.txt
        FileInputStream fIn = null;
        String  dateDec= null;
        String[] date = null;
        Boolean flag = null;
        Calendar cal1 = null;
        Calendar cal2 = null;

        try {
            fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));

        String aDataRow1 = "";
        String aBuffer1 = "";

        try {
            while ((aDataRow1 = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aBuffer1 += aDataRow1;

                myReader.close();
                dateDec = AESencrp.decrypt(aBuffer1); 
                System.out.println("Datedec"+dateDec);
                if(dateDec == ""){
                    flag = false;
                }else {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(flag == true) {

        try
        {   
                System.out.println("checks1");
                //DataBaseActivity openHelperClass = new DataBaseActivity(this);
                myDbHelper = new DataBaseActivity(this);
              //  myDbHelper = new DataBaseActivity(this);

               System.out.println("checks2");
                try {
                    System.out.println("checks3");
                    myDbHelper.createDataBase();
                    System.out.println("checks4");

            } catch (IOException ioe) {

                throw new Error("Unable to create database");

            }
```

The Exception is on the line `dateDec = AESencrp.decrypt(aBuffer1);`

Comment: It seems wrong that you are trying to decrypt `aBuffer1`, each time it is appended with a new line of content. Is that what you are intending it to do?

Comment: No. I want to append single line of content only. but for the security measures I was checking. The file that i made if someone do changes in that file, that I wanted to check

Comment: Is each line encrypted by itself?
If you have two encrypted lines, "asdf=" and "qwer=", you must decrypt them line by line. Trying to decrypt "asdf=qwer=" in one attempt, which is what you are doing, isn't going to work

Comment: no. I got the error where it was throwing. U can check this linkrecently I have asked the ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156140/how-to-calculate-aes-encrypted-data-length